# Apply WHERE after GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with items that are part of a thread, so they have a thread ID, each item also has a date (UNIX timestamp). My table looks something like the following (UNIX timestamps simplified):

```
+-----------------------------+
|  id |   date  |  thread_id  |
+-----+---------+-------------+
|  1  |   1111  |      4      |
|  2  |   1333  |      4      |
|  3  |   1444  |      5      |
|  4  |   1666  |      5      |
+-----------------------------+
```

What I want to do is select thread `IDs` where ALL the items sharing the same thread ID are smaller than the passed date. So if I wanted thread `IDs` where ALL items are older than `1555` (`date < 1555`), I would only expect to have thread `ID 4` returned, not `5` even though it's got an item with a date smaller than `1555`. This is what I tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < 1555 GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY date DESC
```

What I'm trying to do with that query is group all items by thread ID around the item with the highest date value and from there get the items where the date is less than `1555`. But that doesn't work, it will still return thread `ID 5` because it's got an item older than `1555`.

So to summarize, how would I only select thread `IDs` where ALL items are older than a certain date?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT thread_id FROM table GROUP BY thread_id HAVING MAX(date) < 1555
```

Comment: If I want to `SELECT MAX(date) thread_id FROM table GROUP BY thread_id HAVING MAX(date) < 1555`, what about the efficiency? I mean, will the `MAX(date)` be computed twice?

Answer (score 7):

Use a HAVING clause. This allows you to filter on aggregates like SUM, MAX... Here you want to select only those thread id's whose newest entry is older than 1555, so you write:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    GROUP BY thread_id 
    HAVING MAX(date) < 1555
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause prevents the HAVING clause from seeing any dates from 1555 onwards, so the combination of the HAVING condition and the ORDER BY will pick thread 5 first again.  Drop the WHERE clause (this time).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `having` in place of `where`:

```sql
select customer_id,sum(amount),count(amount) from payment group by customer_id 
having sum(amount)> 100
```