# Compare most recent date in 2 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

events:

```
event_id | event_venue 
20160507 | 43 
20160501 | 47
20160424 | 22
```

results:

```
result_event | name | score
20160424 | John | 112 
20160424 | Billy | 113 
20160417 | Steve | 50
```

The `event_id` is just the date code.

The `events` table lists every scheduled event for the year.  The `results` table only lists results that have happened so far.

I want to query the `results` table to see what the last `result_date` entered was, to see if it was from the final event of the year.

This isn't working...

```
SELECT MAX(event_date) as finale, MAX(results.result_date) as lastevent, event_venue
FROM events
JOIN results on results.event_id=events.id
```

With the goal being, `if 'lastevent'='finale' then "FINAL" else event_venue`.

Comment: you want to use HAVING you can check a similar topic for more explenation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466289/apply-where-after-group-by

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple subquery like this:

```
SELECT result_event 
FROM results 
WHERE result_event IN (
    SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM events
);
```

Then if the latest record in **results** table is from the latest event in **events** table you will get the event_id, if not you will get empty result.

Comment: This seems to work.  However, my `events` table and `results` table also have a column for the `series_id`.  I have series "A" and series "B" results.   I tried to add `AND series_id='A'` to the end, but that doesn't work.  How would I add a clause to limit the results from data in a third column?