# Does using HAVING in SQL here compute an aggregate function a second time?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I saw this query as an answer to another question on this site:

```
SELECT MAX(date), thread_id
FROM table
GROUP BY thread_id 
HAVING MAX(date) < 1555
```

With this database sample:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  id |   date  |  thread_id  |
+-----+---------+-------------+
|  1  |   1111  |      4      |
|  2  |   1333  |      4      |
|  3  |   1444  |      5      |
|  4  |   1666  |      5      |
+-----------------------------+
```

Am I correct in assuming `MAX(date)` is computed twice here?

If so, this would definitely reduce the efficiency of this query. Is it possible to refactor the query so that `MAX(date)` is only computed once, so that performance can be maximised?

Comment: No, the max() will only be computed once.

Comment: Why would you not filter the data with a where clause making the having redundant?

Comment: @P.Salmon It's not a query of mine, just mirroring an unanswered question in the comments of [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466320/14146687) out of pure interest.

Comment: The key point in the linked question is 'ALL items for a thread are older than 1555'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peek into the query pipeline/execution plan will answer your question.  During the `GROUP BY` aggregation step, MySQL will compute the max date for each `thread_id`.  Then, during the `HAVING` filter, the max date will already be available to use.  So, I would expect `MAX(date)` to be computed only once.

Note that MySQL actually permits using aliases in the `HAVING` clause, so you could have written your query as:

```sql
SELECT thread_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY thread_id 
HAVING max_date < 1555;
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutly NOT !

The letters SQL means Structured Query Language. The most important word into this name is QUERY that means it is not a procedural language. In a procedural language, you write the exact commands that you want the computer to do. In SQL, a "query" language, you do not write a program code, but only the desired answer, then the SQL algrebrizer/optimizer have to compute the program that will be executed by the query processor (known as "query execution plan").

SQL is translated into relational algebra which is a simple mathematic formula and then be simplified by the algrebrizer like the work you've done at school when the teacher gives you a complex equation to solve : factorization, substitution...

The SQL engine will do the same, by factorizing the MAX(date) that will be compute once only !